# Encrypt file with AES 128 mode cbc using public key X509 V3 (PKCS7)

Tags: c++, c, encryption, cryptography

I need to encrypt file with AES 128 mode cbc.
The key of AES need to encrypt using public key X509 V3.
All this need to save in binary file PKCS7.

```
BIO* certBIO = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)&certData[0], certData.size());
if (certBIO)
    x509 = d2i_X509_bio(certBIO, 0);
BIO_free(certBIO);

sk_X509_push(x509_stack, x509);

BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_write(bio, &inData[0], inData.size());
BIO_flush(bio);

PKCS7* pkcs7_encrypt = PKCS7_encrypt(x509_stack, bio, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), PKCS7_BINARY);

FILE *fpPKCS7 = fopen(szPKCS7File, "wb");
if (!fpPKCS7)
    return 1;

i2d_PKCS7_fp(fpPKCS7, pkcs7_encrypt);
fclose(fpPKCS7);
X509_free(x509);
sk_X509_pop_free(x509_stack, X509_free);
```

Is it correct code ?
The function i2d_PKCS7_fp crashes.

Comment: If it crashes how could the code be correct?

Comment: @zaph It could be a bug in the called function, but I would not put that as a first option.

Comment: @flonder Please [edit] your question to include the appropriate language tag: C *or* C++.

Comment: Didn't C any C++ constructs, added C tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
PKCS7* pkcs7_encrypt = PKCS7_encrypt(x509_stack, bioIn, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), PKCS7_BINARY);

BIO *bioOut = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
BIO_write_filename(bioOut, szPKCS7File);
i2d_PKCS7_bio(bioOut, pkcs7_encrypt);
```

But i have a question else.
What information really in this file ?
Is it contains the encrypted key of AES by public key of certificat ?

Comment: Don't ask questions in answers.